# Convert cells to 0 in dataframe based on values in second dataframe, R

Tags: r

I want to manipulate my dataframe so that cells that produce abundance percentages below a certain threshold (for example I am using 0.1%) are converted to 0s, and those that are above that threshold remain. I can produce a second dataframe where I convert all cells into the abundance percentages, but I don't know how to add to my code so that I obtain a final dataframe filtered with my condition. I am using R `dplyr`

An example of my dataframe and the code I've used so far:

```
df <- tibble(Family = c("Brassicaceae","Betulaceae","Asteraceae","Araceae"), Site1=c(0,100,1000,1), Site2=c(3,1837,1652,0), Site3=c(1,0,5,10))
df
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Family       Site1 Site2 Site3
  <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Brassicaceae     0     3     1
2 Betulaceae     100  1837     0
3 Asteraceae    1000  1652     5
4 Araceae          1     0    10

df.rel <- df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(./sum(.)*100))
df.rel
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Family         Site1   Site2 Site3
  <chr>          <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 Brassicaceae  0       0.0859  6.25
2 Betulaceae    9.08   52.6     0   
3 Asteraceae   90.8    47.3    31.2 
4 Araceae       0.0908  0      62.5
```

Aracea for Site1 had a % abundance < 0.1%, and so did Brassicaceae for Site 2. So those would be converted to 0s while all the other values remain giving me a final dataframe like the following:

Example output:

```
df.final
     Family       Site1 Site2 Site3
  <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Brassicaceae     0     0     1
2 Betulaceae     100  1837     0
3 Asteraceae    1000  1652     5
4 Araceae          0     0    10
```

My knowledge on dplyr is very basic so I'm not sure how to manipulate my first dataframe (`df`) to check the same cell position in `df.rel` and follow the conditions I set.

Answer (score 3):

We need a condition based on the calculation i.e. using `case_when`, check whether the percent from dividing by `sum` is less than 0.1, then convert to 0 or else return the original

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(across(where(is.numeric),
     ~ case_when(./sum(.) * 100 < 0.1 ~ 0, TRUE ~ .)))
```

---

Or even without any `case_when`, just multiply with logical vector (`TRUE` ->1  and `FALSE` -> 0)

```
df %>%
   mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ . * (./sum(.) * 100 >= 0.1)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  Family       Site1 Site2 Site3
  <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Brassicaceae     0     0     1
2 Betulaceae     100  1837     0
3 Asteraceae    1000  1652     5
4 Araceae          0     0    10
```

---

Or using `base R` with `colSums`

```
df[-1] <-  df[-1] * (df[-1]/colSums(df[-1])[col(df[-1])] * 100 >= 0.1)
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know about the case_when function that is very helpful. This also worked so efficiently so I don't need to produce the second dataframe at all. Thanks so much!